# How do I fix this UnknownHostException?

Tags: java, android, url

```
public static final String readURL(String url)throws Throwable
{
        try {
            InputStream in = (InputStream) fetch(url);
            byte[] bArr = readBytes(in);
            return new String(bArr);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            throw e;
            }
}


public static final Object fetch(String address) throws MalformedURLException,IOException {
    URL url = new URL(address);
    Object content = url.getContent();
    return content;
}
```

I am behind a proxy and when I try

readURL("http://abc.com")

to access URL http://abc.com it throws java.net.UnknownHostException:
I have:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

in manifest file.

Any quick solutions?

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432961/how-do-i-make-httpurlconnection-use-a-proxy

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.DIRECT,
    new InetSocketAddress(proxyHost, proxyPort));
url.openConnection(proxy);
```

or

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "my.proxyhost.com");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "1234");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are running your app on ***Emulator*** then do the following-

**1)Close all running emulator.**

**2)Clean your project and Close Eclipse.**

**3)Start the eclipse again.**

**4)Create new emulator and run your project.**

Thats it! worked for me!!!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that fetch does not do the necessary DNS lookups.  If you nslookup abc.com you get a redirect to  www.go.com.  This may be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this, if you are behind the proxy and firewall. The reason is your IE and FF is enabled with proxy setting but emulator is not yet configured.

1. > adb shell
2. ## sqlite3 /data/data/com.google.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db
3. sqlite> INSERT INTO system VALUES(99,’http_proxy', 'proxy:port');
4. sqlite> SELECT * FROM system;

You should be able to see the last inserted value at bottom of your table.

Browse thro this link : [Proxy which requires authentication with Android Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28380/proxy-with-android-emulator)