# Android sdk 2.2 proxy with domain name is not working

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Proxy with Android Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28380/proxy-with-android-emulator)

Android sdk 2.2 proxy with domain name is not working.

emulator -avd prakash1 -http-proxy http://Domain/username:password@proxy:port-debug-proxy

is not working

I tried to set proxy (Domain\username) and port in mobile network. It is not working. Please help me

Answer (score 1):

You can find file: androidtool.cfg on c:\Documents and Settings\YOU USER NAME.android\

and you add line

```
http.proxyLogin=USER@PASSWORD

http.proxyPort=PORTNUMBER

http.proxyHost=PROXYHTTP
```

and save the file and try open ANDROID SDK