# bypass specific web address in an Android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation

Is there anyway to bypass specific server in the android emulator by the -http-proxy  command line parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this answer can help you: [Proxy which requires authentication with Android Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28380/proxy-which-requires-authentication-with-android-emulator)

Or this one: [How to setup Android emulator proxy settings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570627/how-to-setup-android-emulator-proxy-settings)

More info: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html#startup-options